# HTML Function Edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The function I have only responded to a button click but not the image click. Can anyone tell me what would I need to modify in the function so that it responds to both button & image clicks?

```
function clickMe(a,b) {
    $("#q"+b+" input[type='button']").click(function(event) {
        if(event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
        else event.returnValue = false;
        if(b !== $(".qc").length) {
            $("h1").html(a);
            $("#q"+b).hide(250, function() {
                $("#q"+b).next().fadeIn(250);
            });
        } else {
            $("h1").html(a);
            $("#q"+b).hide(250, function() {
                $("#q"+b).next().fadeIn(250, function() {
                    loading(0);
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what does your html looks like? $("#q"+b+" input[type='button']") references an button, it's impossible to know how to point to an image without the html code

Comment: Update your question with your HTML

Comment: Having seen your previous question, I have to ask: do you actually understand what the code is doing? Or are you blindly copy-pasting code from random places on the internet and then wondering why it doesn't work?

Comment: Niet the Dark Absol, I know what the code is doing but not being a programmer I do not know how to correctly code the solution. @arieljuod, I am not trying to point to an image, I want the function to respond to an image click. For example, if I change: input[type='button']") to input[type='image']", then it works with the image click (I've tested it) the problem now is it will no longer respond to a button click. So I want to know the proper code to incorporate both image and button as opposed to one or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably expecting this

```
$("#q"+b+" input[type='button'], #q"+b+" input[type='image']")
```

```
function clickMe(a,b) {
    $("#q"+b+" input[type='button'], #q"+b+" input[type='image']").click(function(event) {
        if(event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
        else event.returnValue = false;
        if(b !== $(".qc").length) {
            $("h1").html(a);
            $("#q"+b).hide(250, function() {
                $("#q"+b).next().fadeIn(250);
            });
        } else {
            $("h1").html(a);
            $("#q"+b).hide(250, function() {
                $("#q"+b).next().fadeIn(250, function() {
                    loading(0);
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I hope this solves your problem. If not then no worries :) just update/add your html in the test case bellow:
https://codebrace.com/editor/b02f036fa

Comment: Yep, It worked like a charm! Thank You, Really appreciate it.